# "processing" error message deploying MVC4 to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2012, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Steps**

- Right-click project, "Publish to AWS"
- Deploy new application with template: "AWS Elastic Beanstalk"
- Name: "mysite", description "mysite", tick "Deploy application incrementally", Next
- Environment name:" mysite", description "mysite", default URL, Next
- Container 64-bit Server 2012 w/IIS 8, instance type Small, Next
- Tick "Enable 32-bit applications", enter valid notification email address, Deploy

**Results**

Output window shows:

```
Commencing deployment for project 0x10c-cloud
...building deployment package obj\Debug\Package\Archive...
...deployment package created at E:\dev\path-to-my-stuff\project-here\obj\Debug\Package\Archive
...build of project archive completed succesfully
...starting deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment 'mysite'
...starting incremental deployment to environment 'mysite'
```

Receive the error popup after 5-10 minutes:

```
Error deploying new application: Unhandled error during deployment: Deployment Failed: Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed with exception: processing .

Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment 'mytest' did not complete successfully
```

Log file at `"C:\Users\Kieren\appdata\local\AWSToolkit\logs\vs2010\log.txt"` contains:

```
2012-12-04 20:04:21,957 [29] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.VS2010Package - Output to AWS output window pane: ...deployment package created at E:\dev\0x10c\Dev\mytest\mytest\obj\Debug\Package\Archive
2012-12-04 20:04:21,957 [7] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.VS2010Package - Output to AWS output window pane: ...build of project archive completed succesfully
2012-12-04 20:04:21,957 [7] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.VS2010Package - ...build of project archive completed succesfully
2012-12-04 20:04:21,970 [88] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.VS2010Package - Output to AWS output window pane: ...starting deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment 'mytest'
2012-12-04 20:04:21,971 [88] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.ElasticBeanstalk.Commands.DeployNewApplicationCommand - Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk: ...starting deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment 'mytest'
2012-12-04 20:04:21,974 [88] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.VS2010Package - Output to AWS output window pane: ...starting incremental deployment to environment 'mytest'
2012-12-04 20:04:21,974 [88] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.ElasticBeanstalk.Commands.DeployNewApplicationCommand - Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk: ...starting incremental deployment to environment 'mytest'
2012-12-04 20:04:21,975 [88] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.ElasticBeanstalk.Commands.DeployNewApplicationCommand - ...staging deployment from work folder E:\dev\0x10c\Dev\0x10c-cloud\0x10c-cloud\obj\Debug\Package\Archive
2012-12-04 20:04:21,975 [88] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.ElasticBeanstalk.Commands.DeployNewApplicationCommand - ...commit repository root set at C:\Users\Kieren\AppData\Local\AWSDeploy\4e72fcb2\
2012-12-04 20:14:21,416 [88] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.VS2010Package - Output to AWS output window pane: Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed with exception: processing .
2012-12-04 20:14:21,417 [88] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.ElasticBeanstalk.Commands.DeployNewApplicationCommand - Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed with exception: processing .
2012-12-04 20:14:21,417 [88] ERROR Amazon.AWSToolkit.ElasticBeanstalk.Commands.DeployNewApplicationCommand - Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed with exception: processing .
2012-12-04 20:14:21,417 [88] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.VS2010Package - Output to AWS output window pane: Error deploying new application: Unhandled error during deployment: Deployment Failed: Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed with exception: processing .
2012-12-04 20:14:21,417 [88] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.ElasticBeanstalk.Commands.DeployNewApplicationCommand - Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Error deploying new application: Unhandled error during deployment: Deployment Failed: Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed with exception: processing .
2012-12-04 20:14:21,417 [88] ERROR Amazon.AWSToolkit.ElasticBeanstalk.Commands.DeployNewApplicationCommand - Error deploying new application: Unhandled error during deployment: Deployment Failed: Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed with exception: processing .
2012-12-04 20:15:07,811 [88] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.VS2010Package - Output to AWS output window pane: Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment 'mytest' did not complete successfully
2012-12-04 20:15:07,814 [88] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.ElasticBeanstalk.Commands.DeployNewApplicationCommand - Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment 'mytest' did not complete successfully
```

**NOTE!** The failure happens almost exactly 10 mins after deployment starts.. a timeout then, I would think.  To fix it, though?.. I've ordered fiber broadband but it doesn't arrive for a week ;)  Also if I redeploy to the same app, it fails sooner: just over one minute, not 10.

Application "exists" in my AWS explorer, but no environment beneath it.

**Things tried**

- I've uninstalled and reinstalled the SDK
- I deleted the AppData\Local\AWSDeploy folder (seems to be the local git repo)
- Deploying to the same EB app or new EB app numerous times

Comment: Note, if I look at my app in AWS explorer, I can create an environment for it.. it seems to work from there, so far (I will update when the environment is healthy or not..).  But the wizard route doesn't work?

Comment: Ok, the wizard doesn't seem to work.  It pushes the new version of the app, but I need to manually publish that to an environment.  I have a workaround, but would appreciate an answer if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: It sounds like deployment failed on the instance. Things to check: The health check URL you configured returns a 200 status code. Failing that, you can get the deployment logs from the environment in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Management Console, or by remoting into the instance and looking in C:\Program Files\AWS Elastic Beanstalk\HostManager\logs

Comment: I will check it out, thanks: but I wonder why it would happen 100% of the time with the wizard and 0% of the time when using the manual SDK tools..

Comment: Ah, there's a problem with that, actually.  As I say, when the process completes, there is no environment (and no instance to remote to) - just an application in the explorer.  No 200 to check for, no log - no instance.

Answer (score 0):

If the healthcheck URL doesn't return a 200, your app will not get deployed. So if you have something happening on startup, such as checking a database you haven't setup quite yet, and your healthcheck URL is hitting that page, you'll get this error.